# Tools for Java template-based String construction

Tags: java, string, templates, construction

I am trying to refactor some legacy code. The task here is to construct lengthy messages/strings based on some pre-defined template that looks like this:

```
field1,8,String
filed2,5,Integer
field3,12,String
......
```

Then I am handed a java object that has all those fields. What needs to be done here is simply get data from the object fields and use them to construct a long message/string based on the template. Some of these fields also may be converted based on some simple rules. For example:

```
abc => a
def => d
ghi => g
```

As a result we need to check the values of these fields from time to time. Also there are rules about padding (mostly adding empty space to the right). So a conostructed message/string may look like this:

```
uater   4751 enterprise  ......
```

Currently we are just using brutal force to do this job. First we feed the template into an ArrayList, each element is a line, eg, "field1,8,String".   During the actual message construction, we loop through this ArrayList, and then fill the data into a StringBuffer. Here is some sample snippet

```
StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer(1000);
for (String field : templateFields) {
    String[] fieldArray = field.split(Constants.SEPARATOR);
    if (fieldArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WORKFLOW)) {
        message.append(rightPad(object.getFieldOne(), Integer.parseInt(fieldArray[1])));
    } else if (fieldArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WORKVOLUME)) {
        message.append(rightPad(object.getFieldTwo(), Integer.parseInt(fieldArray[1]));
    } else if (fieldArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WORKTYPE)) {
        if (object.getFieldThree().equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {
             message.append(rightPad("a", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray[1]));
        } else if (object.getFieldThree().equalsIgnoreCase("def")) {
             message.append(rightPad("d", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray[1]));
        } else {
            message.append(rightPad("g", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray[1]));
        }
    } else if ......
}
```

As you can see, as hidious as it is, it gets the job done. But such code is error-prone, and is hard to maintain. I wonder if you guys have any tools or libraries or some elegant solutions to recommend. 
Thanks so much! Hua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have an approach where you are looping over possible `templateFields`. That's not necessary.

Since every `fieldArray[0]` is compared to some `Constants` values and in case of a match is processed further, we can replace the for-loop by a `Map`. Its keys are the possible `Constants` values and its values are mappers. A mapper is a `BiFunction` which takes the `object` and the value of `fieldArray[1]` and returns for these a message of type `String`.

Let's start with the mappers:

```
public class FieldToMessageMapper {

    private static final Map<String, Function<String, String>> WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER = new HashMap<>();
    static {
      WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER.put("abc", fieldArray1 -> rightPad("a", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray1)));
      WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER.put("def", fieldArray1 -> rightPad("d", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray1)));
      WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER.put("DEFAULT", fieldArray1 -> rightPad("g", Integer.parseInt(fieldArray1)));
    }

    private static Map<String, BiFunction<MyObject, String, String>> MESSAGE_MAPPER = new HashMap<>();
    static {
      MESSAGE_MAPPER.put(Constants.WORKFLOW, (o, fieldArray1) -> rightPad(o.getFieldOne(), Integer.parseInt(fieldArray1)));
      MESSAGE_MAPPER.put(Constants.WORKVOLUME, (o, fieldArray1) -> rightPad(o.getFieldTwo(), Integer.parseInt(fieldArray1)));
      MESSAGE_MAPPER.put(Constants.WORKTYPE,
        (o, fieldArray1) -> WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER.getOrDefault(o.getFieldThree().toLowerCase(), WORKINGTYPE_MESSAGE_MAPPER.get("DEFAULT")).apply(fieldArray1));
    }

    public static Optional<String> map(MyObject o, String fieldArray0, String fieldArray1) {
      return Optional.ofNullable(MESSAGE_MAPPER.get(fieldArray0.toLowerCase()))
        .map(mapper -> mapper.apply(o, fieldArray1));
    }

    private static String rightPad(String string, int pad) {
        // TODO right pad
        return string;
    }
  }
```

We do not return a mapper itself. `FieldToMessageMapper` offers the method `map` which does the mapping. It returns an `Optional<String>` which shows the result might be empty if there is no mapping for the input.
To ensure to get a mapper independent of the characters case, all keys  are `String..toLowerCase()`.

Let's go on with the overall processing:

```
  protected StringBuffer process(Collection<String> templateFields, MyObject object) {
    StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer(1000);
    for (String field : templateFields) {
      String[] fieldArray = field.split(Constants.SEPARATOR);
      String msg = FieldToMessageMapper.map(object, fieldArray[0], fieldArray[1])
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unsupported field %s", field)));
      message.append(msg);
    }
    return message;
  }
```

I don't know how you need to handle missing mappings. I choose fail fast by throwing an exception.

Please note: `StringBuffer` is

> A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters. A string buffer is like
>   a `String`, but can be modified.

If your processing isn't multithreaded you could use `StringBuilder`. If the result isn't modified further, you could use `String`.

Let me show a further alternative using `Stream` which returns a `String`:

```
  protected String process(Collection<String> templateFields, MyObject object) {
    return templateFields.stream()
      .map(field -> field.split(Constants.SEPARATOR))
      .map(fieldArray -> FieldToMessageMapper.map(object, fieldArray[0], fieldArray[1])
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unsupported field %s", Arrays.toString(fieldArray)))))
      .collect(Collectors.joining());
  }
```

---

If I got the code from the question right, there should be the following implementation of `Constants`:

```
  public class Constants {
    public static final String SEPARATOR = ",";
    public static final String WORKFLOW = "field1";
    public static final String WORKVOLUME = "filed2";
    public static final String WORKTYPE = "field3";
  }
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to have a configuration approach you can elaborate this code further to use Spring configuration:

1. Define an interface `MessageMapper` which has two methods: `String getKey()` and `String map(MyObject o, String fieldArray1)`. `getKey()` returns the `Constants` value for which the mapper provides the mapping.
2. Implement each of above `MESSAGE_MAPPER` using this interface.
3. Add a `CommonMessageMapper` which has a constructor `CommonMessageMapper(MessageMapper... messageMappers)`. The `messageMappers` has to be put in a `Map<String, BiFunction<MyObject, String, String>> mappers` like: `mappers.put(messageMapper.getKey(), messageMapper)`. Define a method `String map(MyObject o, String fieldArray0, String fieldArray1)` which will lookup  the appropriate `MessageMapper mm` using `fieldArray0`: `MessageMapper mm = mappers.get(fieldArray0)`. Invoke then `mm.map(o, feldArray1)`. (You may use here also an `Optional` to handle the case when no appropriate mapper is present.)
4. To use Spring configuration all `MessageMapper` and the `CommonMessageMapper` have to be annotated as `Bean` or `Component`. The constructor of `CommonMessageMapper` has to be annotated with `@Autowired`.
5. Define a Spring configuration (either using XML or as [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)) which will inject the desired `MessageMapper` into a `CommonMessageMapper` and has a factory method for such a `CommonMessageMapper`.
6. Use `CommonMessageMapper` instead of `FieldToMessageMapper` above.

Comment: Thanks so much LuCio! I was hoping to get this done mostly through configuration. But I also really like your solution!

Comment: @Hua I've updated my answer showing how to elaborate my approach to a configuration approach.

Comment: Thanks LuCio! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yep. Just did! Thanks again!

Comment: Thx for your [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Glad I can help.